# How to check for existance of dynamically loaded images with Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am using Selenium to test the functionality of web page. A Valve appears open or closed by loading the appropriate PNG file . I need to check if valve is open or closed by checking if right PNG file is loaded
How to do that with Selenium . The Xpath remains the same when either of images are loaded
Here is code behind code for that element

> Blockquote

```
<div comp_type="CustomizedComponent" show_function="loadCustomizedComponent" class="server_binding textCenter" style="position: absolute; left: 521px; top: 26px; width: 84px; height: 50px; text-align: center; background-size: 84px 51px; transform: rotate(0deg); background-image: url(&quot;img/DD6E3CB1.png&quot;); z-index: 15; background-repeat: no-repeat;" range="129" address="3" type="1" length="1" on_text="" off_text="" id="157235533478328" show_param="157235533478328" degree="0" tag_id="Private Tag" on_image="img/10F9F7E8.png" off_image="img/DD6E3CB1.png" mode="false">
```

'

> Blockquote

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: I think you have to share HTML for both case when valve is closed and open. I hope there is change in some html attribute which help to decide valve is open or close.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        string backgroundImg =  Driver.FindElement(By.Id("157235533478328")).GetCssValue("background-image"); 
        if (backgroundImg.Contains("DD6E3CB1.png"))
        {
            //Off image
        }
        else
        {
            //On image
        }
```